# How to send emails dynamically to many users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**1.Explaination**

I can already send an email to a specific user, but now I need to send emails to many users from a list, on submit.
I tried to make a dynamic input of user's email, but no email is sent.

**2. Question**

What is wrong with my code?

How should this be done, in the correct way, to make it work?

**3. The frontend code**

```
     <form method="post" class="border-0 m-1 p-1" style="background-color:#EBF4F7;border-radius:5px;">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        @{
            int i = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model.EmailList)
    {
           
            <div class="form-group" hidden>                
                <select asp-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].UserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId" style="font-size:80%;"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden>
                <input asp-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].SenderEmail" class="form-control" value="sender@testmail.com" readonly style="font-size:80%;" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].SenderEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-1 p-1" style="text-align:center;" >
                <input asp-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].ClientEmail" class="form-control border" value="client@testmail.com" style="font-size:80%;" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].ClientEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-1 p-1" hidden>
                <input asp-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].Subject" class="form-control border" value="Notification..." style="font-size:80%;" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].Subject" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-1 p-1">                
                <input asp-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].Body" class="form-control" type="text" value="the text to be sent " style="font-size:80%;"  />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EmailList[@i].Body" class="text-danger"></span>
                @(i++)
            </div>
           
}
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary font-weight-bold "
                        style="float:unset;min-width:100px;">
                Send
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**4. The OnGet code**

public IList EmailList { get; set; }

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    try
    {
      
        var rr = new List<EmailNotifications>()
    {
        new EmailNotifications() { },
                new EmailNotifications() { },
                new EmailNotifications() { },
                new EmailNotifications() { },
                new EmailNotifications() { },
    };

        EmailList = rr;

        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.EmailUsers.Where(p => p.Nde.Id == userId), "UserId", "UserId");
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.ToString(); }
    return Page();
}
```

**5. The OnPost method**

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<EmailNotifications> EmailList)
        {
 
 using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mytestserver.com", 25))
                {
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // this must be before the **Credentials** else this will reset the given credential                   
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@testmail.com", "mypassword");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = false;

                    //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
                    //smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"wwwroot\maildump";

                    foreach (var nn in EmailList)
                    {
                        var message = new MailMessage
                        {
                            Body = nn.Body,
                            Subject = nn.Subject,
                            From = new MailAddress("sender@testmail.com"),
                            IsBodyHtml = true

                        };
                        message.To.Add(nn.ClientEmail);
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                    }
                }
             

                MessageOk = "Success.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does your `EmailList` in `OnPostAsync` contain any values? If yes, are those values valid? Set a breakpoint at the backend and step through your code ...

Comment: Yes. They contain all the values, till the  foreach (var nn in EmailList){}

Comment: this is the error i get:   .System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> 
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10013): 
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. [::ffff:78.47.166.115]:25 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoMultipleAddressConnectCallback(Object result, 
MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context) 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoMultipleAddressConnectCallback(Object result, MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context)

Comment: What email provider are you using? It seems that the provider has rejected the send requests.

Comment: https://www.smarterasp.net/

Answer (score -1):

This is the full answer that i got from the email server support:

```
Dear Customer,
```

If you wish to use our email service, please set up the following DNS records from your name servers, remove any other duplicated records.

**type: CNAME**

name: mail
value: mail5010.site4now.net
TTL: 3600

**type: MX**

name: @ or blank
value: igw10.site4now.net
TTL:L 3600

**type: TXT**

name: @ or blank
value: v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.site4now.net ?all
TTL: 3600

If someone else finds himself in this situation, you have to add all this three rows on the original website provider (myexample.com), not on the hosting server part.